# Pass value of text_field_tag to controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a text_field_tag whose value I want to pass to the controller.

```
<%= text_field_tag 'amount', 'Enter amount' %>
```

I have a link_to tag already which passes other parameters, and I also want to pass the value of this textbox to my controller action.

```
<%= link_to "Do it", do_it_path(id: some.id, detail: card.summary) %>
```

Can anyone please suggest some ways through which this can be achievable? I want to avoid using a form because it is only one field, and I wish to keep things simple.

Comment: Why would you not use a form? Forms are the simplest way you're going to actually do this! Otherwise I'm going to suggest `onclick` handlers, pseudo-forms, and unnecessary Javascript. Use a form, your end-users will be thankful for it.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. But I am starting out in Rails, so I was wondering is there any other way I could do it.

Comment: The downvote is appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your text_field_tag input is after the DOM is loaded, you'll probably want to use JavaScript to append the value of your text_field_tag to the link click event. The following uses jQuery:

```
<%= text_field_tag "amount", "Enter amount", class: "amount_field" %>

<%= link_to "Do it", do_it_path(id: some.id, detail: card.summary), class: "do_it_link" %>

<script>
  $(".do_it_link").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", function() {
      return this.href + "&amount=" + $('.amount_field').val();
    });
  });
</script>
```

But you really should use a form. It's simpler and more secure.

```
<%= form_for @something do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount, placeholder: "Enter amount" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :detail, value: card.summary %>
  <%= f.submit "Do it" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Learned from both approaches. Although I was looking for a javascript way, I ended up using the form_tag.